# Spring RestTemplate with NTML Authentication

Tags: java, spring

I am consuming a service which is NTML Authentication . 
Below is my configuration
But i am getting 400 Bad Request

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
RequestConfig.Builder requestBuilder = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(5000).setSocketTimeout(10000);
Registry<AuthSchemeProvider> authSchemeRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<AuthSchemeProvider> create().register(AuthSchemes.NTLM, new NTLMSchemeFactory())
        .register(AuthSchemes.NTLM, new SPNegoSchemeFactory()).build();
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new NTCredentials("MyUsername", "MyPassword", "", "MyDomain"));
HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create().setConnectionManager(cm).setDefaultRequestConfig(requestBuilder.build())
        .setDefaultAuthSchemeRegistry(authSchemeRegistry).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("parameters", headers);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(builder.build()));
List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors
        = restTemplate.getInterceptors();
if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(interceptors)) {
    interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
    restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
}
restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(clientHttpRequestInterceptor);
```

The same service i am able to consume using apache http client.
Does spring supports NTML Authentication .?

Comment: Try CNTML if it is windows and put system proxy to CNTML local port.I am sharing my knowledge as I know It is just temporary work around not a perfect solution!

Comment: @positivecrux Any sample Code could help me better understanding